# Can't upload to Heroku with SQLite in test group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, heroku

There is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use RSpec & FactoryGirl for testing
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :test, :development do
    # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Use annotations for models
gem 'annotate', '>=2.6.0'

# Time and date validations
gem 'validates_timeliness'

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

When I use 'git push heroku development:master' I've got the following error:

```
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_b80818e5-941b-4e0a-b519-dfd1f819a11e/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_b80818e5-941b-4e0a-b519-dfd1f819a11e/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local


       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_b80818e5-941b-4e0a-b519-dfd1f819a11e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_b80818e5-941b-4e0a-b519-dfd1f819a11e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have got gem `validate_timeliness` [which requires](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/blob/master/Gemfile#L13) `sqlite3`. As far as I know you can not use anything other than Postgres on Heroku, so you have to get rid of it somehow*. You can use `gem dependency -R` to see dependency tree (but only first level) of your gems.

*** Not true - see comment below.

Comment: You *can* use MYSQL, but you have to define `DATABASE_URL` in your config to point to your MYSQL db